# Shopify Omnisend Custom HTML Signup Form

Tags: forms, shopify, shopify-app

I am using omnisend app for Shopify subscribe list. I am using a custom form to integrate the input data. 
For the ominsend form, they have own class to capture data.
Like this:

```
<form class="my-form omnisend-subscribe-form" action="/subscribe" method="post">
    <input class="omnisend-subscribe-input-email" type="text" placeholder="Enter your email address" />
    <input class="omnisend-subscribe-input-first-name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your first name" />
    <input class="omnisend-subscribe-input-last-name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your last name" />
    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe!">
</form>
```

First Name: **omnisend-subscribe-input-first-name** 
Last Name:  **omnisend-subscribe-input-last-name** 
Email: **omnisend-subscribe-input-email**

But for the birthday input data, I am unable to find the class.
How can I dynamic the birthday input data by class?

```
<form class="my-form omnisend-subscribe-form" action="/subscribe" method="post">
    <input class="omnisend-subscribe-input-email" type="text" placeholder="Enter your email address" />
    <input class="omnisend-subscribe-input-first-name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your first name" />
    <input class="omnisend-subscribe-input-last-name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your last name" />
    <input class="omnisend-subscribe-input-?" type="text" placeholder="MM" />
    <input class="omnisend-subscribe-input-?" type="text" placeholder="DD" />
    <input class="omnisend-subscribe-input-?" type="text" placeholder="YYYY" />
    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe!">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there is no way to collect the birthday form the omnisend form. This form is not support to collect birthday.